# Adding and removing div style with javascript while css still applies

Tags: javascript, css

I have a DIV with a specific ID ("container") on every page of my site as part of the template.

```
#container
{
max-width:980px; min-width:980px; padding-top:6px;
}
```

When a button (to toggle full screen) is clicked i get what is the max supported width of the client and then do:

```
document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('style', 'max-width:' + width + 'px !important;');
document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('style', 'min-width:' + width + 'px !important;');
```

This works fine and sets the max-width to say 1400px.

My question is, can I remove this style I just added, so only the css would apply, using javascript ?

Or is my option having the same code, going back to 980?

```
document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('style', 'max-width:980px !important;');
document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('style', 'min-width:980px !important;');
```

Comment: Are pixels mandatory? Why don't you base yourself on vw units ? Why !important ? You'd be better off with CSS classes, applied conditionally based on fullscreen mode.

Comment: I would make a "fullscreen" css class which overrides the default #container styles.  Then you can simply add a classname to your element when going fullscreen and remove it when not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the entire `style` attribute

```
 document.getElementById('container').removeAttribute('style');
```

Or you can remove only the `max-width` property in the `style` attribute:

```
 document.getElementById('container').style.maxWidth = "none";
```

Refferences:

<kbd>[`style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)</kbd>

<kbd>[`removeAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element/removeAttribute)</kbd>

Comment: Brilliant, I was afraid something like this would also remove any css, it doesn't.

Comment: This doesn't removes CSS, this manipulates the DOM `style` attribute, that overrides the defined CSS styles, but don't change anything in your css files.

Comment: It removes only inline styles.

Comment: @Bonatoc why? can you explain? That's the question I guess. Downvotes are not for fun, remember. And why the other answer is the question but this not?

Comment: @Bonatoc can you come here and explain? Or you are making a troll-marathon ?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude — The question states: "can I remove this style I just added", not all the styles. - Upvoted because of the edit with style.property = "value". I still do think that in this case, going with adding/removing a CSS class is better in the long run, codewise speaking.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is, can I remove this style I just added, so only the css
>   would apply, using javascript ?

You need to use a class here

```
.default-style
{
   max-width:980px; min-width:980px; padding-top:6px;
}
```

so while assigning the new width, remove this class first

```
document.getElementById('container').setAttribute('style', 'max-width:' + width + 'px;min-width:' + width + 'px;');
document.getElementById('container').classList.remove("default-style");
```

When you want to go back to default

```
document.getElementById('container').removeAttribute('style');
document.getElementById('container').classList.add('default-style');
```

Refer to [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) for adding/removing class.

Comment: My point precisely. But again, !important is a bad habit. max-width can be reset to default browser value if needed.

Comment: @Bonatoc Removed the `!important`. It is not required now. I agree that it should be used very carefully

Comment: I'm affraid why this is not downvoted by @Bonatoc . I feel like LOL

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I am not sure about that too. Anyways, I have removed `!important`. `Note that I'm upvoted this answer.` I did yours too, because I liked the simplicity and OP liked it too

Comment: Congratulations , you are liked by  @Bonatoc LOL!!! This is a good answer, but mine was before `:P`

Comment: @gurvinder372 And I (OP) upvoted both of you, he was just tiny bit faster.